# React Native Audio Playing mp3 files with spaces in their names

Tags: javascript, react-native, audio, expo

I have been trying to build a a media player in react native using Expo to be able to play audio on my music project.

I have successfully hacked one together with the preferred design etc but I still have a minor bug. Here, I receive information from an API Endpoint with Links to files stored in a server. this audios play when the filename is just one word. When there are spaces in the name, the file, it does not play. eg .../musics/test.mp3 plays while .../musics/test 32.mp3 does not play. Any idea on how to handle this issue in React native will be highly appreciated. My play function

```
 startPlay = async (index = this.index, playing = false) => {
        const url = this.list[index].url;
        this.index = index;
        console.log(url);
        // Checking if now playing music, if yes stop that
        if(playing) {
            await this.soundObject.stopAsync();
        } else {
            // Checking if item already loaded, if yes just play, else load music before play
            if(this.soundObject._loaded) {
                await this.soundObject.playAsync();
            } else {
                await this.soundObject.loadAsync(url);
                await this.soundObject.playAsync();
            }
        }
    };
```

url is the link to the file .

I am working on a streaming platform and I will love to get a player similar to this:

[image]

Something like this https://hackernoon.com/building-a-music-streaming-app-using-react-native-6d0878a13ba4

But I am using React native expo. All the implementations I have come across online are using native without expo. Any pointers to any already done work on this using expo will be of great help eg packages .

thanks

Comment: Replace each space with `%20`

Comment: How do I do that because the name is returned from an API I have no control over. It simply means I have to read the entire name and replace ?? kind of not an efficient solution

Comment: Take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55547863/2813224). It's a single line of code added to the code you have provided: `const url = encodeURI(uri);` and optionally change the name of a variable: `const uri = this.list[index].url;` Explain how that is inefficient?

Comment: I also have an issue with the file names with spaces while uploading audio files to the server. Can anyone help me to resolve my issue?

Comment: Please check the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71394645/react-native-how-to-upload-audio-files-with-spaces-in-their-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The urls should be encoded:

```
const uri = this.list[index].url;
this.index = index;
const url = encodeURI(uri);
console.log(url);
```

The `uri = "../musics/test 32.mp3"` will be encoded to `url = "../musics/test%2032.mp3"`

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to check the is post since it resolved your problem. ✅

Comment: I checked already. Please do you have an idea of any react native player that works with expo ?? just like that on the screen shared above

Comment: Actually you upvoted by clicking  (thank you), but there's an additional button that looks like a checkmark ✔ which is checked for the answer that resolves the issue and/or best answers the question. [React Expo](https://blog.expo.io/recreating-beats-music-with-react-native-and-expo-snack-172a33dbfe95)

Comment: I also have an issue with the file names with spaces while uploading audio files to the server. Can anyone help me to resolve my issue?

Comment: Please check the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71394645/react-native-how-to-upload-audio-files-with-spaces-in-their-names