# React Native - How to upload Audio files with spaces in their names

Tags: react-native, audio, file-upload, react-redux, upload

I have successfully been able to upload file when the filename is just one word, When there are spaces in the name, the file, I get error from server.

**Example:**  1.] '.../musics/Love.m4a' -> upload successfully
2] '.../musics/Love Thy Neighbor.m4a' -> upload failed

Any idea on how to handle this issue in React native will be highly appreciated.

I have been trying to upload an audio file in react-native but because of space in file name not being able to upload to server, I get below error from a server;

```
**file:**  {uri: 'file:///Users/fathom-d004/Library/Developer/CoreSi…m.brandarmy.user1-Inbox/Love%20Thy%20Neighbor.m4a', 
name: 'Love Thy Neighbor.m4a', type: 'audio/x-m4a'}
```

**error:**  *Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/fathom-d004/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/83619055-D45F-4FA9-85CC-A2009A599EA7/data/Containers/Data/Application/FE596B31-0385-4F77-B342-EF354F86FF1B/tmp/com.brandarmy.user1-Inbox/Love%2520Thy%2520Neighbor.m4a'*

Comment: Can you please tell me how you are getting the audio files, can you share a code snippet, I want something like the image picker library do

Answer (score 0):

Used below simple solution;

I believe I've found the error. The issue was that the file I was uploading had a space in it, so we need to decode the URL first before uploading file to server, like:

```
var decodedURL = decodeURIComponent(file.uri);
const base64 = await fs.readFile(decodedURL, "base64");
```

***Thanks...!***